Multiply a variable in VSCode snippets
How can I multiply a variable in VSCode snippets?
    "Print to console": {
        "scope": "jade, pug",
        "prefix": "fimg",
        "body": [
            "img(src='https://fakeimg.pl/${1:350}x${2:200}/00CED1/FFF/?text=$1x$2' srcset='https://fakeimg.pl/$1x$2/00CED1/FFF/?text=$1x$2 1.5x, https://fakeimg.pl/$1x$2/00CED1/FFF/?text=$1x$2 2x' alt='')"
        ],
        "description": "Fake images"
    }

for dimensions 1.5x increase the variable $1 by one and a half times, and for the multiplier 2x increase it by 2 times

VSCode snippets don't directly support mathematical operations on variables. But you can use a workaround by defining a new variable to hold the multiplied value. Here's how you can modify your snippet to achieve what you're looking for:
"Print to console": {
    "scope": "jade, pug",
    "prefix": "fimg",
    "body": [
        "img(src=`https://fakeimg.pl/${1:350}x${2:200}/00CED1/FFF/?text=${$1}x${$2}` srcset=`https://fakeimg.pl/${$1}x${$2}/00CED1/FFF/?text=${$1}x${$2} 1.5x, https://fakeimg.pl/${Math.floor($1 * 1.5)}x${Math.floor($2 * 1.5)}/00CED1/FFF/?text=${Math.floor($1 * 1.5)}x${Math.floor($2 * 1.5)} 2x` alt='')"
    ],
    "description": "Fake images"
}

${Math.floor($1 * 1.5)} calculates the dimensions for 1.5x multiplier.
${Math.floor($2 * 1.5)} calculates the dimensions for 1.5x multiplier for the second variable.

Thanks for your help, but it doesn't work.
Jade compiler gives an error and requires quotes. If you add quotes, the fakeimg service gives a 404 error

okay, I will try to resolve your problem
